# Why do people access fields in JS constructors, but not set them?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been reading lots of code that looks like this:

```
function Constructor(foo) {
    this.bar;
}
```

for defining constructor methods. Ofcourse, that field read does nothing. Why is it there? In a lot of cases, I do not see comments or tags for documentation generators either.

Comment: Where exactly have you found "lots" of such code?

Comment: Maybe an example of actual code with this construction, in case there's some reason that didn't make it into your explanation? As is, looks dead, yes.

Comment: Perhaps you mean: `this.foo = foo;`. That creates an instance variable for the object you are creating.

Comment: @Pointy: The specific case was motivated by: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/html/saxparser.js line 6581, see TreeParser. I've seen other cases of this, let me try to dig more up.

Comment: These guys do it everywhere. Example: line 447 @ https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/src/e8af8a37f0f14ea1e8c630ecfe6f1b1933794036/src/jqplot.core.js?at=default

Comment: At any rate, judging by the reactions, I guess most people don't do this. I'm still curious though.

Comment: +1 to the documentation guess in this case. I figured I'd mention that it would also trigger a getting function if something happened to have defined a getter for `bar` on the prototype, and that could technically have side-effects, though it'd be awful to actually do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TreeParser` code referenced is doing absolutely nothing.  My guess is that the intention is either 1) to document the object's properties, or 2) the original author is conflating `this.foo` and `this.foo = undefined`, thinking that `this.foo` is akin to `var foo`.  It is not.

For reference the TreeParser is quite similar to the following:

```
function MyStuff(someArg) {
    /**
     * Very brief someArg documentation here.
     */
    this.someArg;

    // Do some other stuff...

    this.someArg = someArg; // <-- This line actually does something useful
}
```

In short, there is no good reason to be writing code like this.  Good documentation is important, but this is not good documentation.

Comment: I too was guessing that people think it initializes the property similar to what you mentioned `this.foo = undefined` and iterable when using `Object.keys()`, but that's not specified anywhere in the spec. *shrug*

Comment: Or it could be a regex replacement gone haywire.

Answer (score 3):

That code is doing absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The argument `foo` and `this.foo` are not the same thing. When you see `this.foo` it refers to a `new` instance of `Constructor`'s `foo` property, while the argument `foo` passes in a value to the `new Constructor` instance, like:

```
function Whatever(foo){
  this.foo = foo;
}
var wht = new Whatever('What are you talking about?');
console.log(wht.foo); wht.foo = 'Something Else.'; console.log(wht.foo);
var wh = new Whatever('This in a different instance of the same constructor.');
console.log(wh.foo);
```

Comment: I'm not asking how javascript works. I'm asking if there's a reason, other than documentation, for specify the fields in the constructor. I guess I got my answer though from everyone's reactions.